# Can I override onBackPressed() for Firebase AuthUI?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

When my user is in Firebase Auth UI's login screen, hitting the back button recreates the screen, it does not inherit the `onBackPressed()` method from the activity it lives in. Is there a way to make the app close from the Firebase login screen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to make it close and go back to the former activity but you have to do this by overridding onStartActivity method in the method it needs to go back to.

Try this in the activity you want it to go back to.
Note: This answer is tailored towards using the prebuilt signIn UI, but the concept is the same when using your own UI for signIn.

In the activity you want the onBackPressed to work for, you must have called:

```
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build(),
    RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Where RC_SIGN_IN is a static final int variable e.g 123. Then, in the same Activity, you have to Override onActivityResult like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Successfully signed in
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        // ...
    } else {
        // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
        // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
        // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
        // ...
        if (response == null) {
                // User pressed back button. NOTE: This is where the back action is
                //taken care of
                return;
            }

            if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                //Show No Internet Notification
                return;
            }

            if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                //Shown Unknown Error Notification
                return;
            }
    }
}
}
```

You can check firebase docs, where some of the code for this answer is gotten from for more info.